# i2c bus not detecting data

Tags: i2c

I have a raspberry pi 3 model B and i am working on a project that sends voltage and current through ADS1115 (ADC) into the RPi but I cant read anything on i2c bus.

I've followed every step on Adrafruit, including the blinka test and everything was ok.
First i thought it was something wrong with my RPi pins, so I executed the pigpio library and all my pins are working.
After that I thought the only problem would be the ADS1115 so I ordered other online and still didnt work...

So I started measuring the pins with a multimeter and my i2s pins (sda and scl) are with the iddle 3.3V but the SCL and SDA pins on the ADS are with 0V

Is this expected?

I tried everything possible to understand what is wrong but I don't know why...

EDIT: Circuit schematics:
[image: https://www.embarcados.com.br/raspberry-pi-e-ads1115/amp/]

Built Circuit:

[Circuit photos](https://imgur.com/gallery/EW3I52j)

Comment: To help we need to see clear photos of the wiring.  A schematic would also be useful so we could check that you have correctly wired.

Comment: Hi @joan, i updated the question with the photos and schematics!

Comment: Are the pins soldered into your ADS breakout board, it will never work if they aren't.

Comment: I can not see a connection between ADDR and ground on the ADS1115.

Comment: @Dougie Yes, they arent soldered... I will buy a soldering iron and test it, thanks you so much!

Comment: @joan I didnt connect the addr to the ground. After the soldering part i will make sure to do it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I see neither a photo nor schematic.

Comment: I didn't notice that the pins on the ADS1115 weren't soldered.  That will certainly stop the device working reliably (if it works at all).